# What representation does to_bytes use in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Example

```
>>> int("1").to_bytes(1, 'big')
b'\x01'
>>> int("55").to_bytes(1, 'big')
b'7'
>>> int("155").to_bytes(1, 'big')
b'\x9b'
>>> int("255").to_bytes(1, 'big')
b'\xff'
```

Numbers 1, 155, and 255 I understand.
They are represented as hexadecimal, that is why there is \x in from.

**But why is 55 represented as b'7' ?**

Not important for problem that I am solving, but would like to know.

Comment: Bytestrings use ASCII characters for values in the printable range (32-126) - that's a lot more compact, and actually human-readable if the content is textual.

Comment: 55 is the ascii code for the character `'7'`.

Comment: `to_bytes` converts an `int` objects into a `bytes` object, of course

Comment: byte 55 is represented as 7 because ord("7") == 55, the `bytes.__repr__` uses ascii for the printable characters. This is probably because `bytes` is simply what `str` *used* to be in Python 2.7. In any case, it doesn't *have* to be that way.